# Error with Brother hl 2240

Tags: 20.04, printing, ubuntu-mate

When I tried to print a document, I got a blinking light on the Brother hl 2240 printer showing error.

It has paper and I could find no jam.

What else can I check for ?

Using ubuntu mate 20.04.

This is one driver I have installed.

```
printer-driver-brlaser
printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I used my DVD and booted to it. I did the "Try Ubuntu without installing option."

I ran Printers but could not find any other diagnostic info than what is supplied on my Ubuntu Mate 20.04 hard drive installation.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Did you install Epson drivers? What is "hl 2240"?

Comment: There is no Epson printer "hl 2240"

Comment: Sorry, I made corrections. @Pilot6

Comment: Install drivers form Brother site.

Comment: Which OS and version are you using?

Comment: I did that. My printer has worked fine until this morning.

Comment: Is everyone stumped?

Comment: I am VERY dissapointed  in the lack of response.

Comment: Does the printer work when connected to an Ubuntu USB live session? If not, then I suspect the problem with the printer  is caused by a hardware issue.

Comment: What is an Ubuntu USB live session? @karel

Comment: @fixit When you boot the USB that is used to install Ubuntu you can select either the *Install Ubuntu* option or the *Try Ubuntu without installing* option. Selecting the second option launches an Ubuntu live session which is also useful for troubleshooting hardware.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the procedure to reset the printer.

Brother HL-2240
Brother HL-2240 - Reset Toner Cartridge

Sometimes the Brother HL-2240 does not reset properly after putting in a new cartridge, and leaves you with a 'toner low' or 'toner empty' message. It is possible to manually reset the printer to remove this message:

Ensure the printer is turned off.
Open the printer front cover.
Hold the Go button while turning the printer on.
When the Toner, Drum, and Error LEDs are on and the Ready LED is off, release the GO button. All of the LEDs will turn off.
Press the Go button two (2) times. The Toner, Drum, and Error LEDs will turn on.
TN420 / TN2210 cartridge - Press the Go button six (6) times, or
TN450 / TN2220 cartridge - Press the Go button seven (7) times.
The Error LED should now be flashing, close the front cover.
```

I did that and the light was still blinking. I was about to salvage parts from the printer when I found a piece of paper that was jammed up.

Printer now working.

I will make a sticker to put on the printer.

It says, "Check for paper jams." :-)